# my page.tpl.php overrides path of page display of views

Tags: views, theming, uri

I created a view and a page display of it. I set a path for it. this is its path

```
http://localhost/myProject/library
```

but when I copy and paste this url in address bar, it just displays my `page.tpl.php` what I have created for front page. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be in the file name - `page.tpl.php` will be used automatically for display of all pages.

If you want to have separate template, use `hook_preprocess_page()`:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (arg(0) == 'library') {
    // This will look for template named page--library.tpl.php in your theme.
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__library';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. do I need to add any special code inside `page--library.tpl.php` to display views fields ?if I want to embed this view in a special region of this page what shall I do? my method for doing such thing is this code `views-embed-view()` and I write this code at any place what I want to display the view.

Comment: No, you don't need any special code to display views fields. Just copy the `page.tpl.php` and make necessary adjustments to the layout. The second part of the question is not quite clear - I suggest creating a new "Question" here so the answers are separated for other people with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing this complete path as `"http://localhost/myProject/library"`.If so please provide relative path instead of absolute path, so relative path would be "`library`" only and then check again visiting `http://localhost/myProject/library` in your url.

Comment: in views interface I only write `library`